# Unable to manage or delete songs from my iPod Shuffle

Tags: macos, ipod, ipod-shuffle

I have 2 iPod Shuffles and iTunes will not let me manage my music manually. It won't show playlists using a brand new MacBook Pro. When I delete a song and confirm the delete twice, the song still remains.

Comment: When was the last time this worked for you as expected and what has changed since then?

Comment: If you’re not looking for an answer that says, start with customer support, here are tips on making an edit so people don’t have to guess your actions. https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y

Comment: it still wont let me manage my music.  i click the music tab next to general settings but it will not allow me to click on any of the tabs or search for anything.

Comment: everything worked great until I setup my new mac book pro.

Comment: on my pc i cant access itunes store I have tried to sign in, authorize and deauthorize, every time i get an itunes error try again later, this has been going on for over 2 months. so angry!!  now i see why more people are leaving itunes and streaming

Answer (score 1):

The latest macOS doesn’t have iTunes.

Here’s a guide to get you started on the recent changes.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210200 - What happened to iTunes?